# How can I add images to a PDF created with Nreco PdfGenrator

Tags: powershell, pdf-generation

I'm using [Nreco PDFGenerator](http://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx) to generate PDFs using the following PowerShell script:

```
$PdfGenerator = "$((Get-Location).Path)\lib\NReco.PdfGenerator.dll"
$Assembly = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($PdfGenerator)
$PdfCreator = New-Object NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter

$PdfCreator.PageHeight = 297
$PdfCreator.PageWidth = 210
$PdfCreator.Zoom = 2
$pdfBytes = $PdfCreator.GeneratePdf([string](gc myhtml.htm))
Add-Content -Value $pdfBytes -Encoding byte -Path "./mypdf.pdf"
```

`myhtml.htm` is a simple HTML document:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
  <body>
    <img src='./img/FancyImage.jpg' alt='Fancy Image' />
  </body>
</html>
```

Everything looks perfectly fine, except that the images are missing...

Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apperently, the answer was right on the projects website / FAQ:

> It is possible to include images by specifying their FULL URL or path (if they're on local filesystem). External CSS and javascript files are also supported.

Answer (score 4):

You have to give physical path of your image, you can add one specific tag and replace like below.

```
htmlToPdf = htmlToPdf.Replace("[FancyImage]", Server.MapPath("~/img/FancyImage.jpg"));
```

I did in my language you can do same thing in your language.

Answer (score 0):

try to jpg convert to base64

example

```
<img src='<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
    9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="' alt='Fancy Image' />
```